# Getting an ENONT error while running my nodejs frontend directory

Tags: node.js

I created a frontend directory using npx create-react-app frontend and then when i go in that directory and npm start it gives me this error:-

```
node:internal/fs/utils:347
    
throw err;
  
^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp;C:'
    at Object.realpathSync (node:fs:2580:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Mern chat app\frontend\node_modules\temp-dir\index.js:9:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Mern chat app\frontend\node_modules\tempy\index.js:5:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14) {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'lstat',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp;C:'
}

Node.js v18.16.0
```

I tried everything `npm update`, `npm cache clear`, `npm cache clear --force`, I reinstalled nodejs y first uninstalling from control panel then from program files and then from appdata\roaming I removed npm and npm-cache and then installed the nodejs long term support version again I don't know what else to do please help

Comment: Make sure you're installing using the latest CRA... `npx create-react-app@latest frontend`

Comment: @Phil yes sorry that was a typo......and I did what you said but the error is still the same

Comment: I think it might be an issue with your `TEMP` or `TMP` environment variable. Looks like it's trying to specify multiple paths (separated by `;`) when it should be a single value. Try [editing it](https://www.howtogeek.com/787217/how-to-edit-environment-variables-on-windows-10-or-11/) and remove the `;C:` suffix

Comment: Nice! Now your task is to find out what's been messing with your env vars 

Comment: @Phil I guess that was the only variable that was faulty